# Missing Assembly Error After Setting SupportedRuntime to 4.6 (System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Recently upgraded a web project to target .Net Framework 4.7.2 (was on 4.6)

I added this line to the app.config

```
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6" />
```

Now when I deploy on a machine with .NET Framework 4.6 installed, I get this error when running the website:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
   at Website.Startup.Main(String[] args)
```

I do not have a binding redirect for this DLL in my app.config/web.config as other questions suggested, nor is this even a referenced DLL in my NuGet packages.

Also, when I deploy the website onto a VM with .NET Framework 4.7.2 installed, it works just fine.

Comment: Let me get this straight, you upgraded a project to target Framework 4.7.2... and then *expected it to continue working on FW 4.6*. Why would you think expect that would work?